# How to calculate proportions of area occupied when one rasters is totally overlapping with another

Tags: raster, grass-gis, overlapping-features

Suppose I have two rasters (here vectorized for visualizing purposes): yellow (Y) and violet (V).

[image]

I want to know the proportion of area each of these rasters occupies compared to the area available. For instance:

- how much of the V raster overlaps with the Y raster, compared to the total area available (Y + V, without counting V twice)?
- how much of the V raster does not overlap with the Y raster, compared to the V area?
- how much of the Y raster does not overlap with the V raster, compared to the Y area?

If V and Y would overlap only partially, a simple approach with some masking and `r.stats` would be enough. But there are specific cases such as this one, where V is totally included in Y (or vice-versa), that I don't know how to manage. First, I would need a way to find out which of my rasters are totally overlapping with (= totally included into) another one. So far the only idea I have has to do with coordinates, but I cannot really frame it... Something like "selects those rasters whose V coordinates (but which ones?) are included in Y coordinates". Then I would have to calculate the proportion. Does anyone know how to tackle this?

This is a simplified representation, usually those rasters are not circular. I am using GRASS 7.8.6 on a server running Ubuntu 18.04.6 from a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 2):

The `r.stats` module would be the right choice if you had two categorical raster maps with multiple category values in each. i.e. a species distribution map to be overlaid on a landcover map. Then you could get a count of cells, or area, for all combinations of species/landcover. Also have a look at `r.report` that does the same thing, with an option to present the results using different area units. These modules might do what you want, even though it seems you have only one raster value in each map.

In this case, if your goal is only to find the intersection between polygon shaped areas from two different raster maps, then I think that vectorizing the raster maps is actually the best approach. Then you can run `v.overlay` with the `and` operator to find the intersection (output to a new vector map), and `v.to.db` with the `area` option on that new intersection map to get its area. If you want the area of one vector **not** intersecting with the other, then there is the `not` operator to `v.overlay`.

Note that if you run v.overlay on two polygons that do not overlap at all, then no output map is created. So you'll have to catch those cases where the original rasters are "discontiguous".

Then to get the proportion of overlap area, you would divide the intersection area by the original area...This can be done with a `db.execute` call, using an SQL statement to update a column in one of the polygon vectors. (But that's a new question...)

Comment: Thanks Micha. I will try this approach and let you know if it works!